# How to draw openlayers features using a google earth basemap

Tags: openlayers, google-earth-plugin

Trying to use [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) to (eventually) load markers, vectors & WMS on top of a google earth plugin base map.  Google Earth does not appear to 'play well with others'.

If I instantiate a map in the 'google way':
    google.earth.createInstance('map', initCB, failCB);

I get a google map that I can add google placemarks to, but I can't pass that instance to OpenLayers.

Using the following:

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map('ol-map');
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());

var gphy = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
    "Google Physical",
    {type: G_PHYSICAL_MAP}
);
var gmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
    "Google Streets", // the default
    {numZoomLevels: 20}
);
var ghyb = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
    "Google Hybrid",
    {type: G_HYBRID_MAP, numZoomLevels: 20}
);
var gsat = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
    "Google Satellite",
    {type: G_SATELLITE_MAP, numZoomLevels: 22}
);
var gearth = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
    "Google Earth",
    {type: G_SATELLITE_3D_MAP}
);

map.addLayers([gphy, gmap, ghyb, gsat, gearth]);

map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(-120, 32), 5)
addMarker();
```

This creates a basic OL map with 5 googly layers. I can see the marker I add when any of the map layers **except** when gearth is selected.  As soon as I load the google earth map, it 'takes over' the entire div.  All the OL controls such as the LayerSwitcher are gone and I haven't been able to figure out how to access the google earth instance from OL.

I'm assuming the markers are still present, but behind the basemap.  Setting the opacity on the basemap has no effect.

Questions:

1. Is this a documented limitation?  I can't find anything that indicated it should not be possible.
2. Is there a workaround where I can pass the OpenLayers map/layer instance to google earth's getEarthInstance call? Or vice versa? It seems like that would be the best of both worlds, giving me access to the GE API when needed, but I could use all the WFS processing in OL for most tasks.

Half-baked ideas welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, OpenLayers has absolutely no support for the Google Earth 3D mode. (I'm a developer for OpenLayers, and I only became aware that this was *possible* via this question.) Because of the way that the 3D display code works (via a 3rd party plugin), I can not imagine any way that the default OpenLayers tools -- for drawing, etc. -- are going to work: the pieces that OpenLayers would need to integrate with simply don't exist in the 3D API.

OpenLayers -- primarily being a 2D drawing client -- is unlikely to ever implement something that would translate all of its various calls into Google Maps/Earth API calls.

OpenLayers does have support for Protocols and Formats: in theory, this would allow you to use the OpenLayers WFS processing toolchain to some extent when interacting with third party APIs like the Google Earth API. However, I expect that in this case, you don't gain sufficiently enough from this to solve your problem.

In short: This doesn't work, and there is no simple solution. If you want 3D, you'll probably need to build a lot more yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I'm also in contact with a couple of google engineers, so if I learn anything, I will keep you posted.

Comment: You are correct.  My talk with the google engineers didn't help with this, but did point out that if you want to implement the Google Earth Plugin into a custom-built web application, the local copy of the GE Plugin API (earth_loader_plugin.js) must be loaded and some environment variables must be set to configure the API key and location of the error page for the GEE Server.  An example web page loading the Google Earth Plugin, and connecting to a private GEE Server, may be viewed at http://gmdemo.keyhole.com/geplugin/gee-basic-example.html for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I think this question was related to Google Maps v2, since I don't think there's a type: G_SATELLITE_3D_MAP in v3.

The Google Earth Plugin for Google Maps v3 is (beta) supported via a [script from the google-maps-utility-library-v3 (googleearth.js)](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/source/browse/trunk/googleearth/src/googleearth.js)

The approach the author [@jlivni](https://twitter.com/jlivni) has taken is to listen to Google Maps v3 add/remove events and add corresponding Google Earth Api objects.
I believe a similar approach could be used with OpenLayers. I'm new to OpenLayers, and have just started looking into this but I'll post updated here.

The only thing I can add now is about the initialization of the Google Earth plugin, that is different in v3:

```
function GoogleEarth( olmap ) {
this.olmap_ = olmap;
this.layer_ = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
    "Google Earth",
    {type: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE, numZoomLevels: 22, visibility: false}
);
this.olmap_.addLayers([ this.layer_ ]);
this.map_ = this.layer_.mapObject;
this.mapDiv_ = this.map_.getDiv();

...
var earthMapType = /** @type {google.maps.MapType} */({
tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
maxZoom: 19,
name: this.earthTitle_,
// The alt helps the findMapTypeControlDiv work.
alt: this.earthTitle_,
getTile:
  /**
   * @param {google.maps.Point} tileCoord the tile coordinate.
   * @param {number} zoom the zoom level.
   * @param {Node} ownerDocument n/a.
   * @return {Node} the overlay.
   */
  function(tileCoord, zoom, ownerDocument) {
    var div = ownerDocument.createElement('DIV');
    return div;
  }
});

this.map_.mapTypes.set(GoogleEarth.MAP_TYPE_ID, earthMapType);

this.layer_.type = GoogleEarth.MAP_TYPE_ID;

var that = this;
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'maptypeid_changed', function() {
  that.mapTypeChanged_();
  }); 
}
```

The convoluted part is that we need to define a new map type for Google Earth, and add this type to a Google Map object. But the Google Map object doesn't exist if we don't create a layer with a type, that I set initially to google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE.
Not very clean, but at least it gets me to the same state as the author of this post with Google Maps v3.
Finally there may be a way to make OpenLayers controls visible by modifying the function findMapTypeControlDiv_():

```
var mapTypeControlDiv = this.findMapTypeControlDiv_();
if (mapTypeControlDiv) {
  this.setZIndexes_(mapTypeControlDiv);
  this.addShim_(mapTypeControlDiv);
}
```

[Update]

I've modified the function findMapTypeControlDiv_() and now I look for the OpenLayers LayerSwitcher instead:

```
GoogleEarth.prototype.findLayerSwitcherDiv_ = function() {
//  var title = 'title="' + this.earthTitle_ + '"';
  var id = 'LayerSwitcher';

  var siblings = this.controlDiv_.parentNode.childNodes;
  for (var i = 0, sibling; sibling = siblings[i]; i++) {
    if (sibling.id.indexOf(id) != -1) {
      return sibling;
    }
  }
};
```

The z index of the LayerSwitcher is correctly set and the div shows on top until google.earth.createInstance() is invoked, then it disappears. I'll spend some more time on it, it doesn't look to hard to solve.

[Update 2]

I've worked around the LayerSwitcher panel issue. The trick was attaching the Google Earth Plugin div to the proper div (the original code for GMaps attaches it to the Map Controls array). The other issue was setting the zIndex to make sure the LayerSwitcher is on top.
I'm still having a problem when the GE Plugin is running and I try to minimize the LayerSwitcher, a call to OpenLayers.Event.stop() makes the GE Plugin crash (Chrome) or the LayerSwitcher to disappear (IE8).
I'd like to fork the original code from Google and make a GE Plugin Layer that works on OpenLayers.
Could anyone suggest how to do it? thanks.

Anyway, here are my latest changes:

```
GoogleEarth.prototype.findLayerSwitcherDiv_ = function() {
  var id = 'LayerSwitcher';

  var siblings = this.mapDiv_.parentNode.childNodes;
  for (var i = 0, sibling; sibling = siblings[i]; i++) {
    if (sibling.id.indexOf(id) != -1) {
      return sibling;
    }
  }
};

GoogleEarth.prototype.addEarthControl_ = function() {
...
inner.appendChild(earthDiv);
var parentNode = this.findLayerSwitcherDiv_().parentNode;
parentNode.appendChild( control );

...
GoogleEarth.prototype.setZIndexes_ = function(mapTypeControlDiv) {
  var oldIndex = mapTypeControlDiv.style.zIndex;
  var siblings = this.controlDiv_.parentNode.childNodes;
  for (var i = 0, sibling; sibling = siblings[i]; i++) {
    sibling['__gme_ozi'] = sibling.style.zIndex;
    // Sets the zIndex of all controls to be behind Earth.
    sibling.style.zIndex = 0;
  }

  mapTypeControlDiv['__gme_ozi'] = oldIndex;
  this.controlDiv_.style.zIndex = 2000;
  mapTypeControlDiv.style.zIndex = 2001;
};
```

[update 3]
I've set up a github project here: https://github.com/ZiglioUK/GoogleEarth-for-OpenLayers

Comment: hi, the update 4 URL is returning 404, also tried 'update 3' seems to be outdated. do you have a working set available?

Answer (score 0):

I am not that familiar with the different layer types in OpenLayers anymore, but the key is that the Google Earth API and the Google Maps API are really different beasts.  At first glance I do not see why you would need to add it to a Google Maps type (assuming that's what I think it is).

As Chris implied already, just treat your Earth API integration as an entirely new and separate thing from any existing Google layers; the syntax and concepts in these API's are not really similar enough for you to get any advantage of subclassing the existing Google Maps integration in OpenLayers at least as far as I can tell.

That said I hope the code for the Maps V3/Earth integration will be helpful and analogous to what you need to do to integrate it with OpenLayers.  Meanwhile I've seen some other folks also give this a shot, such as this geoExt example which you may also find useful: http://dev.geoext.org/sandbox/cmoullet/ux/GoogleEarthPanel/examples/GoogleEarthPanelExample.html